# SQL Server compound query

Tags: sql-server

Hello and thanks for looking.

I wrote a simple application for my softball team and I am having some issues with the query I need to rewrite.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    _StartDate, _RescheduleDate, _GameTime, _FieldNumber, _Notes
FROM
    _Schedule
WHERE
    (_StartDate >= DATEADD(wk, 0, { fn NOW() })) 
    AND (_StartDate < DATEADD(wk, 1, { fn NOW() }))
```

This query simply gets the upcoming weeks game schedule. What I need to do and I had forgotten, was to check also for `_RescheduleDates` we currently have 1 or 2 games that are rescheduled.  So somehow I need to modify this to check if reschedule date has a valid date and not "TBD" or NULL.

The second problem is, our games are on Friday, on the day of the game, this changes the data on the website to next weeks game and I need it to not change until the day after the game which is Saturdays. I tried adding 1 day

```
(wk, 1 +1d {fn NOW() }))
```

But obviously this did not work. So I would surely appreciate some help with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    _StartDate, _RescheduleDate, _GameTime, _FieldNumber, _Notes
from (
    select distinct
        _NewDate = coalesce(nullif(_RescheduleDate,'TBD'),_StartDate)
        ,_StartDate
        ,_RescheduleDate
        ,_GameTime
        ,_FieldNumber
        ,_Notes
        from _Schedule
    ) sch
where (_NewDate >= cast(getdate() as date))
    and (_NewDate < dateadd(wk, 1, getdate()))
```

Your "games fall off a day early" issue is because you are comparing the current time to a date--so the time component is assumed to be `00:00:00.000`. This is why you'll see advice against storing the start date and start time in separate columns. Note that `cast(getdate() as date)` requires SQL 2008 or higher; use `cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)` for earlier versions.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d171/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us the desired result from a setup as such:

```
declare @_Schedule table (_StartDate datetime, _RescheduleDate datetime, _GameTime datetime, _FieldNumber int, _Notes varchar(10))
insert into @_Schedule
    select '2013-05-31', null,          '10:30:00', 1, '...' union all
    select '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03',  '10:30:00', 1, '...' union all
    select '2013-06-04', null,          '10:30:00', 1, '...' union all
    select '2013-06-05', null,          '10:30:00', 1, '...'


SELECT DISTINCT 
    _StartDate, _RescheduleDate, _GameTime, _FieldNumber, _Notes
FROM
    @_Schedule
WHERE
    (_StartDate >= DATEADD(wk, 0, getdate())) 
    AND (_StartDate < DATEADD(wk, 1, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

What needs to happen when you are "checking" the _RescheduleDate value?

If you want another query for only the rescheduled games so you can have this on a separate page or section of the website, just modify the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  _StartDate, _RescheduleDate, _GameTime, _FieldNumber, _Notes
FROM
  _Schedule
WHERE
  (_StartDate >= DATEADD(wk, 0, { fn NOW() })) 
  AND (_StartDate < DATEADD(wk, 1, { fn NOW() }))
  AND _RescheduleDate IS NOT NULL
  AND _RescheduleDate <> 'TBD'
```

Otherwise the CASE statement will be able to 'check' for the value upon selecting the values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    _StartDate
, CASE 
     WHEN _RescheduleDate IS NULL THEN ''
     WHEN _RescheduleDate = 'TBD' THEN '' 
     ELSE --do something with the valid datetime 
  END AS _RescheduleDate
, _GameTime, _FieldNumber, _Notes
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of wanted it included in the current statement. I know it is possible I just am not sure about how to go about it.  The schedule page needs to show all games to be played which includes regular scheduled games and also rescheduled games.

Nathan I think  you are onto something.. select results like 'data format' for rescheduled games. Do you know how to create a compound select statement?  I tried to find an example online and haven't found one applicable yet.